# I am not techy in any way, so could anyone advise as to keeping the first 30 characters in a cell and delete any after that.

Tags: excel-formula

I am not techy in any way, so could anyone advise, in plain language,  as to keeping the first 30 characters in a cell and delete any after that. I can do it using another cell, but want to keep it in the same cell. i.e String in cell A1, is "The Best of Dire Straits & Mark Knopfler - Private Investigations". I can remove the characters using len & left etc in cell B1, but it does not copy to another program. When copied all it does is copy the formula, not the result. I want to keep the result so it can be copied. Hope someone understands this. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter formula `<result cell>=LEFT(<cell address of string to truncate>,<length you want>)`

Then do copy/paste special - values only - over the top of your formulas - or into a seperate sheet with the paste - so you can preserve your formulas...
......